# Angular 5 - bind Function parameter incorrect data type translation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a component that basically shows a list of items, and when the user clicks on a particular one then perform an action. That's the basic use case. For this I have the following html template.

```
template: `
  <ul class="list" *ngFor="let item of items">
   <li>(click)="onItemClick(item.id)"</li>
  </ul>
`,
```

My typescript code:

```
export class Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export class ListComponent {

    let items: Map<string, Item>;

    public onItemClick(id: string) {
        console.log(id);
        let item = items.get(id); //this fails to find anything as id for some reason happens to be number.
        processItem(id)
    }

    private processItem(id: string) {
        //some work
    }
}
```

I have been getting around this by the following in the html

```
 <li>(click)="onItemClick(''+item.id)"</li>
```

Appending an empty string forces Angular to pass a string instead of number. But this seems very inconvenient. My understanding was in case of a bind function Angular will accordingly try to case the parameter to the type the function expects.

Did anyone experience this?
I am using Angular 5.2.1 with Typescript 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not cast any data for you. Because TypeScript is not existing in the runtime and JavaScript does not know which types you use in your TypeScript code + TypeScript does not do any implicit types conversion / coercion and it never promised to do so.

I don't really understand what is the basement of *My understanding was in case of a bind function Angular will accordingly try to case the parameter to the type the function expects*: it is never said anywhere.

If you want to ensure your id is a string use simple cast `items.get(String(id))`.

Comment: I developed an understanding myself looking at other examples online to think that there is type handling behind the scenes. However when I saw that this wasn't happening then it made me think, perhaps my typescript configuration is out of place or something. But your explanation helps here. Thx for the clarification.

Comment: @AnandNadar you are welcome :) it's probably a bit hard to understand from the beginning the lifecycle of typescript projects...